# Misunderstanding of C++ array structure

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ and I learned with different tutorials, in one of them I found an example of code:
I have pointed by numbers of lines, that I completely do not understand;

1. Does this array in array or something like that?
2. I can understand the second call, but what is the first doing? There is already
   "coordinates[blocks[num]]", aren't there? Why need again blocks(i) ?
3. How do you make this part of the code easier?  Did struct with this arrays
       don't make easier getting value from arrays?

Thanks in advance!

```
// Global vars
Struct Rect {
   float left;
}

Rectangle *coordinates;
int *blocks;

coordinates = new Rect[25];
blocks = new int[25];
// in method storing values 
const int currentBlock = 0; //var in cycle
coordinates[currentBlock].left = column;  
blocks[currentBlock] = currentBlock;     

//get element method
const Rect& classA::Coords(int num) const 
{
    return coordinates[blocks[num]]; //(2)
}

//and calling this method like
Coords(blocks[i]);  //(3)
Coords(i);          //(3)
// (4)
```

Comment: The line Coords(blocks[i]) is technically wrong, though it won't throw an error. since you are derefrencing blocks within Coords, you don't need to do it when you call the function. Or you should always call with it derefrenced and stop doing it within the function. Whatever suits you. See what Poldie said.

Comment: thanks! i will remember about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, not really. Lots of people will think of them as arrays and even describe them as arrays, but they're actually not. `coordinates` and `blocks` are both *pointers*. They just store a single address of a `Rect` and an `int` respectively.

   However, when you do `coordinates = new Rect[25];`, for example, you are allocating an array of 25 `Rect`s and setting the pointer `coordinates` to point at the first element in that array. So, while `coordinates` itself is a pointer, it's pointing at the first element in an array.

   You can index `coordinates` and `blocks` like you would an array. For example, `coordinates[3]` will access the 4th element of the array of `Rect`s you allocated. The reason why this behaves the same as arrays is because it actually is the same. When you have an actual array `arr`, for example, and you do `arr[4]`, the array first gets converted to a pointer to its first element and then the indexing occurs.
2. No, this is not an array of arrays. What it is doing is looking up a value in one array (`blocks[num]`) and using that to index the next array (`coordinates[blocks[num]]`). So one array is storing indices into the other array.
3. I'll ignore that this won't compile, but in both cases you are passing an `int` to the `Coords` function. The first case looks incorrect, but might not be. It is taking the value at `blocks[i]`, passing that to the function then using that value to index `blocks` to get another value, then using that other value to index `coordinates`. In the second case, you are just passing `i`, which is being used to index `blocks` to give you a value with which you index `coordinates`.
4. That's a broad question that I don't think I can answer without knowing exactly what you want to simplify and without seeing some real valid code.

Comment: In this tutorial main theme is big structures of data, so i thought about making struct with easier way of getting value, because array with array of indices is a little hard for me now, with other big thanks, brilliant !